# Is this still a verification test on a Mock?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd, moq

As the title suggests really. WriteData will be called for each split CSV item in DataIn. I want to determine that WriteData has been called successfully. By adding a callback and doing an assert against the list is this still a mock verify.

```
    [Test]
    public void DataIn_GoodRead_LoggedToFile()
    {
        Moq.Mock<IFileLogger> mock;
        MyLogic logic = SetupLogic(out mock);

        List<string> dataLogged = new List<string>();

        mock.Setup(x => x.WriteData(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Callback(delegate(string s) { dataLogged.Add(s); });

        logic.DataIn(1, "1,2,3");

        Assert.AreEqual(3, dataLogged.Count);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you're using the callback. It seems that

```
mock.Setup(x => x.WriteData(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable()

...

mock.Verify(x => x.WriteData(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(3))
```

would do the same.

And I think you could also avoid the setup and just use the verify line so you would only have

```
mock.Verify(x => x.WriteData(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(3))
```